# Does Nehemiah Gordon self-identify as a Christian?

Tags: reference-request, judaism, jews

Does [Nehemiah Gordon](https://www.nehemiaswall.com/about-nehemia-gordon) self-identify as a Christian? Does he believe that **Yeshua** is the **Christ** ?

I heard that his conversion story exists on the internet but I am unable to find it. If someone can help me find it that would be great.

Comment: For the scholarly purposes of this site, a Christian is anyone who self-identifies as a Christian. People have different definitions for what it means to really be a Christian.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karaite_Judaism.  He is a Karaite Jew.  The conversion stories are about his involvement in converting Christians to the same brand of Judaism that he follows

Comment: @Kris with some references that would make a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an article that examines the beliefs of Nehemiah Gordon and briefly mentions that although brought up in an Orthodox Jewish family, he converted to Karaite Judaism after he moved to Israel in 1993. The article gives a critical overview of Nehemiah Gordon’s book ‘The Hebrew Yeshua versus the Greek Jesus (Hilkiah Press, 2005).  Apparently he rejects Jesus as the Messiah:

> I still do not believe Yeshua to be the Messiah; like all Karaites I eagerly await the coming of the anointed Davidic king who will reign as king over Israel, ushering in an era of eternal peace...
>
> It seems more and more that Yeshua may have been a first century Karaite opposing man-made laws of the Rabbis and returning people to the Torah.

For the purpose of answering your question, it would seem that Nehemiah Gordon does not believe that the Jesus of the New Testament is the Christ, or Messiah.

Source: https://carm.org/nehemia-gordon

Comment: This question has been put on hold as off topic but you did ask if this person believes if Yeshua is the Christ - which strikes me as being a doctrinal issue. Never mind. Glad to have been of some help.